# Spring MVC restful Json is too large to be truncated

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I am try to use restful controller to return the json format data  with MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.
but I found my json data was truncated when the json data is too larger.
Anyone could help to what's the cause or what setting should I supplied?

Comment: Where is the evidence that it is being truncated?

Comment: And how much do you think is *too large*?